# Cómo funciona accion propia en Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Básicamente conozco el uso del Intent pero en este caso me quedo incógnitas. Necesito comprender mejor el intent del siguiente fragmento de código (esto fue creado por otro desarrollador, lo estoy analizando):

```
private void Mensaje(String mensaje){
    Intent i = new Intent(Mensajeria.MENSAJE);//Aquí esta mi duda :(
    i.putExtra("key_mensaje",mensaje);
           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

Luego existe una static String en la clase Mensajería.java que sería lo siguiente:

```
public static final String MENSAJE = "MENSAJE";// Acción en cuestión
private BroadcastReceiver bR;
```

Y en ésta clase se recibe las cadenas intruducidas en el intent anterior:

```
 bR = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String mensaje = intent.getStringExtra("key_mensaje");
            Log.i("Tag: ",mensaje);

            }
        }
    };
```

Por qué le puso "MENSAJES" como acción y en qué le funciona esto? desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Se llama *Intent implícita*, y [está muy bien explicado aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=es-419#ExampleSend), en el idioma de Cervantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta haciendo es ejecutar una acción aqui abajo de dejo una descripción de los diferentes usos que le puedes dar al **intent**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Link de la documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Para ejecutar la acción debe de estar registrado con **IntentFilter** El registro de una acción se suele utilizar para el uso de Broadcast Receiver, entonces al quedar registrado la acción y al ejecutar el siguiente codigo:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
```

Lo que haces es enviar esa acción (en este caso enviar un `String` mendiate `putExtra`que es la manera de enviar datos entre actividades) y el broadcast receiver la va a detectar como si fuera un **Listener**, una vez ejecutado el codigo anterior accedes de manera automatica dentro de la clase Broadcast Receiver que tengas declarado para realizar cierta acción dentro de:

```
 **@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String mensaje = intent.getStringExtra("key_mensaje");
            Log.i("Tag: ",mensaje);

            }
        }**
```

Comment: ahh, ya comprendo, muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos, ya tengo bien Claro.!